# Best way for conditionally (and verbosely) run a command in bash

Tags: bash

I have written a shell script (bash) which runs some commands. It has an option to not to run the commands but to echo them to the screen. By default, the output of these commands is redirected to /dev/null but there is another option to show the output on the screen.

I use a function to check for the value of these variables and run the commands or simulate them:

```
runmaybe() {
    if [[ true = $dry_run ]]; then
            echo "Simulating '$@'"
    else
            if [[ true = $verbose ]]; then
                    $@
            else
                    $@ > /dev/null
            fi
    fi
}
```

The function is working but I had some issues with complex commands such as:

```
 runmaybe eval svn cp $url $root/tags/$ntag -m \"Tagging revision with $ntag\"
```

I had to add the eval to prevent [wordsplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) so svn gets the right value for the -m option.

I have some other complex commands in that script such as:

```
runmaybe vzctl exec 1 "( cd /var/wwww/vhosts/myhost ; php cron.php )"
runmaybe ssh -t user@$host "vzctl exec $vmid \"( /usr/local/bin/myscript )\"" 2>/dev/null
runmaybe rsync --delete --exclude=\"**/.svn/\" --exclude=\"**/.git/\" --include=*.exe --numeric-ids -a $vOpt -H $LOCAL_VM$dir $host:$REMOTE_VM$dir
```

Although the script is working right now, I wonder if there is a better way of doing this task.

Comment: Remember to check y our scripts with http://shellcheck.net to remove most common mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I have checked spellcheck and it is awsome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in unquoted expansion of `$@`. As a rule of a thumb, if you see `$`, you should put it inside `"`. Unquoted expansions undergo word splitting and filename expansions - to prevent them, quote the expansion.

> I had to add the eval

`eval` is evil. Do not use it.

```
runmaybe() {
    if [[ true = $dry_run ]]; then
            echo "Simulating '$*'"
            # or better quote with printf in some corner cases
            printf "Simulating:"
            printf " %q" "$@"
            printf "\n"
    elif [[ true = $verbose ]]; then
            "$@"
    else
            "$@" > /dev/null
    fi
}

runmaybe svn cp "$url" "$root/tags/$ntag" -m "Tagging revision with $ntag"
runmaybe rsync --delete --exclude="**/.svn/" --exclude="**/.git/" --include="*.exe" --numeric-ids -a "$vOpt" -H "$LOCAL_VM$dir" "$host:$REMOTE_VM$dir"
```

Comment: The mistake is already pointed out, but I would like to also add that you could use `exec ${@}` to make it a bit nicer to read. Also note the curly brackets. Even though, you are not doing variable expansion in that example, it is a nice practice :).

Comment: in `exec ${@}`  the `$@` is unquoted and `exec` would terminate the execution of current shell. I see no value in adding braces and I have not encountered a code style guide or reference where expansion with braces or without braces would be advised or preferred over the other - it is purely a cosmetic issue.